# Laravel - refactor table names (migration) will Models/Controllers go with it?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to rename a table in the database from *topics* to *galleries* and I have created a migration that will rename my table.
`Schema::rename('foo', 'bar');`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class RenameTopicsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::rename('topics', 'galleries');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
        Schema::rename('galleries', 'topics');
    }
}
```

However will the Topic Model and Topic Controller be automatically renamed? Or will I have to refactor my code? Does Laravel provide a way to do this easily?

In short my question is - How do you change your schema easily in laravel? (models/controllers/database/requests/transformers ect..)

Comment: Laravel will not touch your controller or models, you have to do that manually. Or may be you can use the IDE's search replace after upgrading the schema.

Comment: TY for the insight @MoeenBasra. How would you recommend doing this? I am using phpstorm and it does refactoring.

Comment: If its a small project then you can easily refactor and can redo if anything goes wrong. If its a big one Then use search replace very very carefully.
click on root directory of you project, hit Ctrl+shift+R and entry the search and replace fileds. Then update files one by one after going through the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question. Laravel does not provide a out-of-the-box way to rename your tables at the same time as your Models/Controllers.

You must manually refactor your code after you change your database schema.

An example of this is lets say i have a posts table and i want to rename it to blogs. Well my posts model and posts controller wont be helpful after i update the schema so i will need to change those over as well. Routes will need to be updated. If I am using views those will need to be updated. In my case i was using transformers and requests so those need to be manually updated.

If you can, try to avoid changing your schema :D